# How to enter data for 3 index parameter in CPLEX OPL?

Tags: cplex

I have a variable X[i][j][k] in my problem. How do I enter data for this in .dat file in CPLEX ?

Lets suppose i=2, j=2, k=3

Supplier 1(i)  Component 1(j)  20 30 40
               Component 2     50 20 10
Supplier 2     Component 1(j)  20 80 40
               Component 2     10 20 10

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the example:

```
CPLEX_Studio127\opl\examples\opl\models\YieldStochastic
```

where you will see in the `.mod`:

```
{string} classes = {"First", "Business", "Economy"};
int capacity[classes] = [37, 38, 47];

// Planned periods 
range periods = 1..3;

// 3 scenarios are studied with their corresponding probability
range scenarios = 1..3;
float probaScenarios[scenarios] = [0.1, 0.7, 0.2];

// 3 pricing options for each class and period
range options = 1..3;
int priceOptions[periods][classes][options] = ...;
```

and then in the `.dat`:

```
priceOptions = 
  [[[1200,1000,950],
    [900,800,600],
    [500,300,200]],
   [[1400,1300,1150],
    [1100,900,750],
    [700,400,350]],
   [[1500,900,850],
    [820,800,500],
    [480,470,450]]];
```